# Normalize 3 database tables

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

Hello I have a problem seperating my 3 payment types: **CASH, CREDIT, BANK**

Each of them has different details.
The details are user defined which means that in a credit card payment (for ex: you should input your credit card details, bank details, cash details (currency and etc))

1. Business Process: The user will choose his payment type in a
   combobox:
2. Then the user will input the details of that payment type.

This is what I've tried:

PaymentType(PaymentType_ID(PK), PaymentTypes)

...
.....
......
.........

then I'm stuck. I don't know how. Please help me. If you will answer explain to me please. I don't want to ask the same question here again. If I'm faced with a similar situation.

***I can't merge all of them into 1 table because they different columns. They have different specific details...

Comment: Payment types don't have different details. *Payments* have different details.

Answer (score 0):

All three payment types have a few things in common. They all have an account number, an amount, a timestamp, a payment type, and some kind of transaction identifier.  All the common attributes go in one table. (Some of the data types are deliberately naive, because they're application-dependent, and I don't know your application.)

```
create table payment_types (
  payment_type_code char(2) primary key,
  payment_type varchar(8) not null unique
);
insert into payment_types values
('Ca', 'Cash'),('Cr', 'Credit'),('Ba', 'Bank');

create table payments (
  transaction_id integer primary key,
  account_code varchar(5) not null, -- references accounts, not shown
  amount_usd numeric(5,2) not null,
  payment_type_code char(2) not null references payment_types (payment_type_code),
  transaction_timestamp timestamp not null default current_timestamp,
  unique (transaction_id, payment_type_code)
);
```

The unique constraint on {transaction_id, payment_type_code} lets SQL use that pair of columns as the target for a foreign key constraint. That's crucial to keeping the rows from the several tables from getting mixed up.

Each payment has different attributes, depending on the payment type. And each payment can be of only one type.

```
create table payment_cash (
  transaction_id integer primary key,
  payment_type_code char(2) not null default 'Ca' check (payment_type_code = 'Ca'),
  foreign key (transaction_id, payment_type_code) 
    references payments (transaction_id, payment_type_code),
  other_cash_columns char(1) not null
);

create table payment_credit (
  transaction_id integer primary key,
  payment_type_code char(2) not null default 'Cr' check (payment_type_code = 'Cr'),
  foreign key (transaction_id, payment_type_code) 
    references payments (transaction_id, payment_type_code),
  other_credit_columns char(1) not null
);

create table payment_bank (
  transaction_id integer primary key,
  payment_type_code char(2) not null default 'Ba' check (payment_type_code = 'Ba'),
  foreign key (transaction_id, payment_type_code) 
    references payments (transaction_id, payment_type_code),
  other_bank_columns char(1) not null
);
```

The default value and check constraint for payment_type_code makes it impossible, for example, to insert credit details for a cash payment.  That *would* be possible--and it would be a Bad Thing--if the foreign key constraint used only the transaction id.

As a general rule, you don't cascade updates or deletes for financial transactions. Instead, correct errors by inserting a compensating transaction.

To make this more friendly to users and application code, create three updatable views that join the payments table to the detail.  How to make them updatable depends on your dbms.

```
create view credit_payments_all as
select p.transaction_id, p.account_code, p.amount_usd, 
       p.payment_type_code, p.transaction_timestamp,
       c.other_credit_columns
from payments p
inner join payment_credit c on c.transaction_id = p.transaction_id

-- Rules, triggers, stored procedures, functions, or whatever you need
-- to make this view updatable.
```

Then any code that needs to insert a credit transaction can just insert into the view credit_payments_all.